# Android/Java: Rounding up a number to get no decimal

Tags: java, integer, rounding

How to round up a decimal number to a whole number.

> 3.50 => 4
>
> 4.5 => 5
>
> 3.4 => 3

How do you do this in Java? Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

And if you're working with only positive numbers, you can also use int i = (int)(d + 0.5).

EDIT: if you want to round negative numbers up (towards positive infinity, such that -5.4 becomes -5, for example), you can use this as well.  If you want to round to the higher magnitude (rounding -5.4 to -6), you would be well advised to use some other function put forth by another answer.

Answer (score 27):

With the standard rounding function?  [`Math.round()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#round%28double%29)

There's also `Math.floor()` and `Math.ceil()`, depending on what you need.

Answer (score 13):

You can use

`int i = Math.round(f);
long l = Math.round(d);`

where `f` and `d` are of type `float` and `double`, respectively.

Comment: `Math.round()` returns `long` - not `int`.

Answer (score 2):

Java provides a few functions in the Math class to do this.  For your case, try `Math.ceil(4.5)` which will return 5.

Answer (score 2):

```
new BigDecimal(3.4);
Integer result = BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP;
```

Or

```
Int i = (int)(202.22d);
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Math.max you can do it like this:

```
(int) Math.max(1, (long) Math.ceil((double) (34) / 25)
```

This would give you 2

Answer (score 0):

Use Math.round() method rounds a number to the nearest integer.
Examples :
2.49 will be rounded down 2
2.5 will be rounded up 3

Comment: You provided an answer for the question of "how to round to the closest number", whereas the actual question was "how to round a number to its higher bound if it's not an integer"

Comment: Pardon me, but I don't see how your answer provides anything that does not already appear in the other answers.