# round up number in Android

Tags: android

I wish to round up a number in android application with coding as shown below.

```
 float num1= Float.parseFloat(n1.getText().toString());
 float num2= Float.parseFloat(n2.getText().toString());
 float outc = num1/input;
 int final1;
```

The application getting user input for `num1` and `num2`, and perform to find outc. I wish to rounding up the `outc` to become an integer `final1` where like below:

```
if outc = 3.8 , final1= 4
if outc = 8.01 , final1= 9
if outc = 12.21 , final1= 13
if outc = 20.45 , final1= 21
```

*only involve positive value

I try to search for solution, and found that mostly they are normal rounding up solution like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11396658/android-java-rounding-up-a-number-to-get-no-decimal).
It that anyway to perform round up as I mentioned?
Thank you.

Comment: if `Math.ceil(num1/input )` do not work for you, try `num1/input+ (num1 % input == 0) ? 0 : 1` for your outc

Comment: The responses in the post that you linked should work for you

Comment: Thank for help. the Math.ceil(num1/input ) is worked. I 'm actually confuse by the Big decimal of responses in the linked post. Thanks everyone again

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Math.ceil()](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Math.html#ceil(double))

```
int result = (int) Math.ceil(outc);
```

BTW, you can't name variable `final`, it is reserved word.

Comment: 2 solutions in 1 :D

Comment: Ya thanks a lot for it!! and that one I should type  `final1`, I corrected it.

Comment: this did not work for me. I passed 1.9999... and ceil gave me 1

Comment: @leeCoder There's something wrong. `Math.ceil(1.9999)` gives me `2.0`. Can you write your code here or in a new question?

Answer (score 2):

Use the ceil function described in:
https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Math.html#ceil(double)